# Python Regex - + metacharacter not being greedy

Tags: python, regex

I have this string.

> string = """Horseradish CULTURE: Well-drained, friable soil with a pH
>   range of 6.2-6.8 will yield the best results. When roots are received,
>   work the soil about a foot deep and incorporate compost, manure, or
>   fertilizer. Make a 5-6" deep furrow and plant root cuttings 12" apart,
>   slanted 2-3" deep with the flat-cut end up..."""

and this code

```
seed_spacing = re.search(r'(?:sow|transplant|plant)(?:(?!rows).)+(\d+)(\'|") apart', string, re.I)
seed_spacing.group()
>>>Make a 5-6" deep furrow and plant root cuttings 12" apart
seed_spacing.group(1)
>>>2
```

I want to see `12`, but I am getting `2`. I need this to be flexible for cases in which it is a one digit number. I thought `+` was greedy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` is greedy - but it's not *just* greedy in `\d+`, it's *also* greedy in `(?:(?!rows).)+`.  The latter is eating the `1`.  Perhaps you'd like `(?:(?!rows)\D)+` better (that is, eat characters that *aren't* digits).

Answer (score 3):

This part

```
(?:(?!rows).)+
```

of  your regular expression is greedy and it matches till `1`, so make it non-greedy like this

```
(?:(?!rows).)+?
```

You will get

```
seed_spacing.group(1)
```

as

```
12
```